# R: Sorting factor by level frequency and plotting

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plyr, r-factor

I have a *data.frame* with several factors such as:

```
df<-data.frame(Var1=as.factor(sample(c("AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF"), 1000, replace=TRUE)))
```

with

```
summary(df$Var1)
 AB  BC  CD  DE  EF 
209 195 178 221 197
```

I want to plot the frequency of the levels of each factor in the *data.frame* as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(1), fill=factor(Var1)))+
       geom_bar(width=1, colour="black")+
       coord_polar(theta="y")+
       theme_void()
```

However, the order of the levels is alphabetically and not by frequency. Using *count* from *library(plyr)* I can create a new data.frame that gives me the frequency of each level:

```
df_count <-count(df, "Var1")
Var1 freq
1   AB  209
2   BC  195
3   CD  178
4   DE  221
5   EF  197
```

Which I can then reorder using

```
df_count$Var1<-factor(df_count$Var1, levels=df_count$Var1[order(df_count$freq, decreasing=TRUE)])
```

which when plotted give me what I want, the sorted frequency of each level.

1.) Is this the most elegant solution? It gives me an extra data.frame for each factor/column in my original data.frame, and I feel there must be a simpler way.

2.) When plotting, how can I rename the legend lables and ensure they are allocated the right factor level? If I use

```
scale_fill_manual(labels=c("Name of AB", "Name of BC", "Name of CD", "Name of DE","Name of EF"))
```

the labels do not relate to the right level. Here the first entry in the legend will be "DE" as it is the level with the highest frequency but the label will say "Name of AB" as defined in *scale_fill_manual.*  I could check the order of the labels manually each time but there must be an automatic way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `reorder()`, I think. In general `reorder(x,y,FUN)` changes the order of levels of a factor `x` according to the results of applying function `FUN` to a second variable `y`.  In this case, you can use `FUN=length`, and it doesn't really matter what you use for `y`.

Set up data (I chose to modify the probabilities to make the result clearer):

```
set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame(Var1=as.factor(sample(c("AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF"),
                            prob=c(0.1,0.5,0.2,0.05,0.15),
                                   1000, replace=TRUE)))
```

Basic plot (wrong order):

```
library(ggplot2)
print(g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(1), fill=Var1))+
   geom_bar(width=1, colour="black")+
   coord_polar(theta="y")+
   theme_void())
```

[image]

Now reorder:

```
df$Var1 <- reorder(df$Var1,df$Var1,FUN=length)
levels(df$Var1)
## [1] "DE" "AB" "EF" "CD" "BC"
```

Check that the order is right:

```
sort(table(df$Var1))
##  DE  AB  EF  CD  BC 
##  46 105 163 189 497
```

Print the new plot (stick in the new data with `%+%` and flip the order of the legend with `guide_legend()`: you could also use `function(x) -length(x)` as `FUN` to change the order of the levels in the first place).

```
print(g1 %+% df + 
    scale_fill_discrete(guide=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! Combined with aosmith's hint how to properly use named vectors it works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 8):

Functions from package *forcats* can help with the factor order.  In particular, `fct_infreq` will set the order of the levels based on the frequency of each level.

```
library(forcats)

df$Var1 = fct_infreq(df$Var1)
```

You can use named vectors to avoid order in the `scale_*_manual` functions.

```
scale_fill_manual(labels = c(AB = "Name of AB", 
                      BC = "Name of BC", 
                      CD = "Name of CD", 
                      DE = "Name of DE", 
                      EF = "Name of EF"))
```

So your plot code could look something like

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = fct_infreq(Var1) ))+
    geom_bar(width = 1, colour = "black")+
    coord_polar(theta = "y")+
    theme_void() +
    scale_fill_discrete(labels = c(AB = "Name of AB", 
                          BC = "Name of BC", 
                          CD = "Name of CD", 
                          DE = "Name of DE", 
                          EF = "Name of EF"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I decided to take Ben Bolker's answer as it only uses base functions, but your explanation on how to properly use vectors for labels was very helpful :-)

Answer (score 6):

You also have a simple solution using the library `forcats`, and the function `fct_infreq`.

```
library(forcats)
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = fct_infreq(Var1)))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = "black")+
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Var1"))
```

[image: Pie chart]

Note that the pie chart is considered evil (you can google that), and you can convey the same information with a simple bar chart :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = fct_infreq(Var1), fill = fct_infreq(Var1))) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab("Var1")
```

[image: Bar chart]